# Can not use PIP or easy_install because deleted /etc/lib/python2.7/urllib.py

Tags: package-management, python-2.7

Like said on title, by a slip of the keys I issued the command:

```
sudo rm /etc/lib/python2.7/urllib.py
sudo rm /etc/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py
```

And with that the problems started, Ubuntu still starts, but when I now want to do anything with pip or easy_install, I get this error:

```
.....
import sys, os.path, re, urlparse, urllib, urllib2, shutil, random, socket, cSt$
ImportError: No module named urllib
```

How can I recover it?

UPDATE:

I reinstall python2.7 based on the answer of [sagarchalise](https://askubuntu.com/users/1543/sagarchalise) but when I search with pip comand then now I get following issue:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 104, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/search.py", line 34, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, index_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/search.py", line 48, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1292, in single_request
    self.send_content(h, request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1439, in send_content
    connection.endheaders(request_body)
TypeError: endheaders() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Any help here would be appriciated.

Comment: Try reinstalling python `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7 python2.7-minimal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General answer if you accidentally remove or overwrite files from packages:

1. Find out to which package your file belongs

   dpkg -S urllib2.py

Answers:

```
python2.7: /usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py
```

1. Reinstall package

   sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7

File is now restored

Comment: Thanks all of you guys...
I solved this issue by reinstall python2.7, pip, setuptools and distribute.